# Specific SQL query for invariant locales

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a table with the same descriptions on many languages for one object. I need to construct a select query to get one needed description having user locale, invariant locale, and if any of the locales will not match with data in the table get one random record.

```
+---+----+--------+--------+-------------+
|   | id | locale | object | description |
+---+----+--------+--------+-------------+
| 1 | 1  | it     | cat    | gatto       |
| 2 | 2  | pl     | cat    | kot         |
| 3 | 3  | de     | cat    | Katze       |
| 4 | 4  | en     | cat    | cat         |
+---+----+--------+--------+-------------+
```

- If user locale is 'it' and the default is 'en', must return -> gatto;
- If user locale is 'ru' and the default is 'en', must return -> cat;
- If user locale is 'ru' and the default is 'po', must return -> any record;

Do you know any variant of query which can do that thing?

Comment: Are you using sqlite, or oracle? Please retain only the relevant tag.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I've mistaken, sql server instead of sql lite, and use both of the (oracle and sql server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `coalesce()` and conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select
    coalesce(
        max(case when locale = :user_locale then description end),
        max(case when locale = :default_locale then description end)
    )
from mytable
where object = 'cat'
```

Where `:user_locale` is the parameter that contains the user locale and `:default_locale` contains the default locale.

Comment: Hi, can we use some another function instead of `MAX()` cause I use SELECT on multiple tables and columns and I get `not a single-group group function`? I google it and it fixes by using group by, but with this, I get duplicated columns.

Comment: @ArtemBahniuk: it is not really possible to answer this without seeing many more details. You probably want to ask a new question, providing sample data, expected resuts, and describing where you are stuck in your current attempt.

Comment: I agree with you. But anyway I found the solution for me, I used this select as subselect in my query and exception has gone. Thank you for your solution

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do is split the table in three entity to avoid redondance in the column "object" AND to avoid violating [3rd normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) (with column "object" and "description" being in functional dependence with locale wich is not the key).

[image]

So you will have the following table :

```
Locale(id_locale, locale)
-->id_locale is primary key
Object(id_object, code)
--> id_object is primary key
Locale_Tran(id_locale,id_object, description)
--> (id_locale, id_object) is composed primary key
--> id_locale is foreign key references on Locale(id_locale)
--> id_object is foreign key references on Object(id_object)
```

(I choose the name for the table but of course you can adapt it to your actual model)

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST
USE TEST

CREATE TABLE [LOCALE]
(
id_locale INT IDENTITY(1,1),
locale CHAR(2),
CONSTRAINT pk_locale PRIMARY KEY(id_locale)
);

CREATE TABLE [USER]
(
id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
locale INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_user_locale FOREIGN KEY(locale) REFERENCES LOCALE(id_locale)
);

CREATE TABLE [OBJECT]
(
id_object INT IDENTITY(1,1),
code VARCHAR(100),
CONSTRAINT pk_object PRIMARY KEY(id_object)
);

CREATE TABLE [LOCALE_TRAN]
(
id_locale INT,
id_object INT,
[description] VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_tran_locale FOREIGN KEY(id_locale) REFERENCES [LOCALE](id_locale),
CONSTRAINT fk_locale_object FOREIGN KEY(id_object) REFERENCES [OBJECT](id_object),
CONSTRAINT pk_locale_tran PRIMARY KEY(id_locale, id_object)
)

INSERT INTO LOCALE
(locale)
VALUES
('IT'),
('FR'),
('PL'),
('DE'),
('EN'),
('RU');

INSERT INTO [USER]
(locale)
VALUES
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6),
(6),
(1)


INSERT INTO [OBJECT]
(code)
VALUES
('CAT'),
('FISH');

INSERT INTO [LOCALE_TRAN]
VALUES
(1,1,'gatto'),
(2,1,'chat'),
(3,1,'kot'),
(4,1,'katze'),
(5,1,'cat'),
(1,2,'pesce')
```

Here is the query :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.getTran
GO;

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getTran
(
    @userLocale CHAR(2),
    @defaultLocale CHAR(2),
    @objectId INT
)
AS
SELECT @userLocale = (SELECT id_locale FROM LOCALE l WHERE l.locale = @userLocale);
SELECT @defaultLocale = (SELECT id_locale FROM LOCALE l WHERE l.locale = @defaultLocale);

SELECT
 coalesce(
        max(case when id_locale = @userLocale then [description] end),
        max(case when id_locale = @defaultLocale then [description] end)
    )
FROM
(
SELECT lt.id_locale, lt.[description]
FROM  [LOCALE_TRAN] lt WHERE lt.id_object = @objectId
) AS t  
GO;


EXEC dbo.getTran 'FR','EN', '1'
```

I don't really found how to have the random locale and i didn't really understand why you wanna do that... But i will try.

Comment: Hi Vincent, Can you please show an example of the query to get localize description? cause for that design we also should use `coalesce()` for various variants of the locale.

Comment: Hello, as i wasn't know wich design you will preffer (because you totaly have the right to keep yours) i haven't write the querry for your question. As i'm a little bit busy right now, i'll write it tonight when i'll be home

Answer (score 0):

Apply your conditions inside CTEs with the use of NOT EXISTS:

```
with
  cte1 as (select description from tablename where locale = ParamLocale),
  cte2 as (
    select t.description from tablename t 
    where t.locale = ParamDefault
    and not exists (select 1 from cte1)
  ),
  cte3 as (
    select * from cte1
    union all
    select * from cte2
  )
select description from cte3
union all
select * from (
  select description from tablename
  where not exists (select 1 from cte3)
  order by random() limit 1
)
```

Change *ParamLocale* and *ParamDefault* with your parameters.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ewUyLrzmHN238CdwZKMQtJ/1).